# Loading the contents of a section tag from external file

Tags: html, polymer

I have a Polymer web app which I've generated with Yeoman. The below fragment shows how pages are defined in the index.html:

```
            <iron-pages attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="{{route}}">

                <section data-route="home">
                    <paper-material elevation="1">
                        <my-greeting></my-greeting>
                    </paper-material>
                </section>

                <section data-route="users">
                    <paper-material elevation="1">
                        <h2 class="paper-font-display2">Users</h2>

                        <p>This is the users section</p>
                        <a href="/users/Rob">Rob</a>
                    </paper-material>
                </section>
```

So basically you define a section for each page.

Is it possible to define these sections as references to some external files? I would not want to add everything in the main index.html as it will get messy pretty soon.

Comment: Assuming you can't use php, the only way I can think of doing this with pure html would be to use frames. A really ugly solution may be to create empty div elements and use javascript to load the html content, but I seriously wouldn't recommend going down that route.

Comment: Yes, PHP is not an option, only HTML + JS. What I'd like to do is a kind of client side routing, but having all the pages in one file doesn't sound like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but not in HTML unless you use ajax/ iFrames(No) to load the content and that would get ugly and would stop crawlers from properly crawling all your pages.

You would need to convert your pages to Java, Python, PHP, .net frameworks.

Since you sound new to this, I would just advise you to use WordPress.
There are many template there and it is easy to create and customise in the future.

Typically client side routing is used in single page applications, where the server-side code is primarily used to provide a RESTful API the client-side code uses via Ajax.

Then you would be look at using Angluar.js

Comment: No WordPress thanks :) I'm new to Polymer yes, but I'd like to learn it as it's much more capable than WordPress (as in applicable to a much broader range of problems). I'm just trying to find a good way of doing client side routing.

Comment: Im not that used to polymer, the only way I know to import HTML into is using <link rel="import" href="my-custom-element.html">

Comment: You will still need to include the contents of that import into our host html.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
Here's a cleaner version to do this:

```
<dom-module id="dyn-import">
<template>
    <div id="container">
        <link rel="import" href="{{href}}"/>
    </div>
</template>
</dom-module>
<script>
(function() {
    Polymer({
        is: 'dyn-import',
        properties: {
            href: {
                type: String,
                notify: true
            }
        },
        attached: function() {
            var container = this.$.container;
            var link = Polymer.dom(container).querySelector('link[rel="import"]');
            link.addEventListener('load', function() {
                var importedDoc = link.import;
                var importedNode = document.importNode(importedDoc.firstChild, true);
                container.innerHTML = importedNode.innerHTML;
            });
        }
    });
})();
```

The imported HTML can contain Polymer elements, that's working fine. The whole thing doesn't seem to be working on Safari. Also, I still seem to have some issues around relative URLS (say the imported HTML fragment references another Polymer element using HTML import - it does seem to work, but there's an error on the console and the URL in the error seems to have been constructed like this: web appreciation host + relative url which is clearly wrong).

I have finally solved this by writing a Polymer component (well, after all it's a Polymer application :)

```
<dom-module id="dyn-import">
    <template>
        <div id="{{id}}">
            <link rel="import" href="{{href}}"/>
        </div>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
(function() {
    Polymer({
        is: 'dyn-import',
        properties: {
            href: {
                type: String,
                notify: true
            },
            id: {
                type: String,
                notify: true
            }
        },
        ready: function() {
            this.id = "ID_" + new Date().getTime();
        },
        attached: function() {
            var sel = d3.select('#'+this.id);
            var link = sel.select('link[rel="import"]');
            link[0][0].addEventListener('load', function() {
                var importedDoc = link[0][0].import;
                var importedNode = document.importNode(importedDoc.firstChild, true);
                sel.html(importedNode.innerHTML);
            });
        }
    });
})();
</script>
```

This can then be used in the index.html as follows:

```
<section data-route="contact">
    <paper-material elevation="1">
        <dyn-import href="elements/contacts.html"></dyn-import>
    </paper-material>
</section>
```

I have one further concern, is it a search engine friendly solution?

Comment: I think the funky business around the ID isn't really necessary, but I don't yet know how to do it better :)